Select Dropdown Search Filter on JSGrid
I am using JSGRID to display records in my laravel blade view. I want to make one of the fields a dropdown selectible menu. So far  I have achieved that using the following
$(document).ready(function() {

    var stations = [
        { Id : 1,  Name : "NAIROBI"},
        { Id : 2,  Name : "EMBU"},
        { Id : 14, Name : "MWEA"},
        { Id : 15, Name : "RUNYENJES"},
        { Id : 16, Name : "CHUKA"},
        { Id : 17, Name : "MATUU"},
        { Id : 18, Name : "MTWAPA"},
        { Id : 19, Name : "KARURUMO"},
        { Id : 20, Name : "KATHWANA"},
        { Id : 21, Name : "MERU"},
        { Id : 22, Name : "KIRITIRI"},
        { Id : 23, Name : "KIVAA"},
        { Id : 24, Name : "CHIAKARIGA"},
        { Id : 25, Name : "ISHIARA"},
        { Id : 26, Name : "MITUNGUU"},
        { Id : 27, Name : "TUNYAI"},
        { Id : 28, Name : "KIBUGU"},
        { Id : 29, Name : "NKUBU"},
        { Id : 30, Name : "kitui"},
        { Id : 31, Name : "SIAKAGO"},
        { Id : 32, Name : "MOMBASA"},
        { Id : 33, Name : "VOI"},
        { Id : 34, Name : "THIKA"},
        { Id : 35, Name : "EMBU STAGE"},
        { Id : 36, Name : "NAIROBI ERUSHA HSE"},
        { Id : 37, Name : "MWINGI"},
        { Id : 38, Name : "KYENI"},
        { Id : 39, Name : "KANYONYO"},
        { Id : 40, Name : "KABATI"},
        { Id : 41, Name : "KATHAGERI"},
        { Id : 42, Name : "KATHAGERU"},
        { Id : 43, Name : "NENO MWEA OFFICE2"},
        { Id : 44, Name : "kisasi"},
        { Id : 46, Name : "KAEWA"},
        { Id : 47, Name : "RUIRU"},
        { Id : 48, Name : "CHANGAMWE"}
    ];

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({

        width: "100%",
        height: "auto",

        loadIndication: true,
        loadMessage: "Please, wait...",
        loadShading: true,

        pageLoading: true,
        pageIndex: 1,
        pageSize: 20,

        inserting: false,
        editing: false,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        filtering: true,
        autoload: true,

        rowClick: function(args) {
            var $row = this.rowByItem(args.item),
            selectedRow = $("#jsGrid").find('tr.highlight');

            // Remove highlight from any previously highlighted row
            if (selectedRow.length) {
                selectedRow.toggleClass('highlight');
            }

            // Highlight the clicked row
            $row.toggleClass("highlight");
        },

        controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "{{ route('delivery.outgoing_delivery') }}",
                    data: filter,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        var stations = response.stationArray
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.error("Error loading data:", textStatus, errorThrown); // Debugging line
                    }
                });
            }
        },

        fields: [
            {
                name: "rowIndex",
                title: "#",
                type: "number",
                width: 30,
                align: "center",
                filtering: false,
                itemTemplate: function(_, item) {
                    return $.inArray(item, $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("option", "data")) + 1;
                    }
            },
            { name: "DELIVERY", type: "text", width: 80, validate: "required" },
            {
                name: "DESTINATION",
                type: "select",
                items: stations,
                valueField: "Id",
                textField: "Name",
                filterTemplate: function() {
                    var $select = jsGrid.fields.select.prototype.filterTemplate.call(this);
                    $select.prepend($("<option>").prop("value", "0").text("(All)"));
                    return $select;
                }
            },

            { name: "PARCELS", type: "text", width: 60, validate: "required" },
            { name: "CREATED AT", type: "text", width: 100, validate: "required" },
            { name: "VERIFIED AT", type: "text", width: 100, validate: "required" },
            { name: "VEHICLE", type: "text", width: 70 },
            {
                name: "VERIFIED",
                type: "text",
                width: 50,
                filtering: false,
                validate: "required",
                itemTemplate: function(value) {
                    return value == 1 ? '<i style="color: green;font-size: 16px" class="ti ti-square-rounded-check"></i>' : '<i style="color: red;font-size: 16px" class="ti ti-xbox-x"></i>';
                }
            },
            {
                type: "control",
                filtering: false,
                itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
                    return $("<a>")
                        .attr({
                            href: "#",
                            'data-bs-toggle': 'modal',
                            'data-bs-target': '#modal-outgoing',
                            'data-id': item.DELIVERY
                        })
                        .addClass("ti ti-eye-down")
                        .css({
                            "font-size": "15px",
                            "text-decoration": "none"
                        })
                        .html('<span class="sr-only"></span>');
                }
            }

        ],
    });
});

I want the DESTINATION field to be selectible. I have partly achieved this functionality using logic from this dribble snippet
The issue I am now experiencing is that all the other columns in the table have there respectable data all except the DESTINATION field. The search input at the top has data that allows me to select locations as desired but the column itself has no data


I was wondering whether I have done something wrong or I am missing something
This is partial code from my laravel controller
// Execute the query with the bindings
        $query = DB::select($sql, $bindings);

        // Format data to match jsGrid requirements
        $output = [];
        foreach($query as $transaction){
            $output[] =
            [
                "DELIVERY" => $transaction->delivery_id,
                "DESTINATION" => $transaction->destination,
                "PARCELS" => $transaction->parcel_count,
                "CREATED AT" => $transaction->created_at,
                "VERIFIED AT" => $transaction->verified_at,
                "VEHICLE" => $transaction->delivery_vehicle,
                "VERIFIED" => $transaction->verified,
            ];
        };

        return response()->json([
            'data' => $output,
            'itemsCount' => $totalCount,
        ]);


Is this a JS problem, a Laravel problem, or an SQL problem?

This was a JS problem

After much research I realized that since I are using valueField: "Id" and textField: "Name" in my grid's configuration for the DESTINATION field, I needed to ensure that the data I was returning from the database was the ID of the destination and not the name. This way, when the grid loads the data, it will map the ID from the data (which corresponds to the valueField) to the appropriate Name in the dropdown (which corresponds to the textField).
This stackoverflow question helped in arriving to this finding.
My final JSGRDI script now looked like this
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({

        width: "100%",
        height: "auto",

        loadIndication: true,
        loadMessage: "Please, wait...",
        loadShading: true,

        pageLoading: true,
        pageIndex: 1,
        pageSize: 20,

        inserting: false,
        editing: false,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        filtering: true,
        autoload: true,

        rowClick: function(args) {
            var $row = this.rowByItem(args.item),
            selectedRow = $("#jsGrid").find('tr.highlight');

            // Remove highlight from any previously highlighted row
            if (selectedRow.length) {
                selectedRow.toggleClass('highlight');
            }

            // Highlight the clicked row
            $row.toggleClass("highlight");
        },

        controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "{{ route('delivery.outgoing_delivery') }}",
                    data: filter,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                       
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.error("Error loading data:", textStatus, errorThrown); // Debugging line
                    }
                });
            }
        },

        fields: [
            {
                name: "rowIndex",
                title: "#",
                type: "number",
                width: 30,
                align: "center",
                filtering: false,
                itemTemplate: function(_, item) {
                    return $.inArray(item, $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("option", "data")) + 1;
                    }
            },
            { name: "DELIVERY", type: "text", width: 80, validate: "required" },
            {
                name: "DESTINATION",
                type: "select",
                items: [
                    { Id : 1,  Name : "NAIROBI"},
                    { Id : 2,  Name : "EMBU"},
                    { Id : 14, Name : "MWEA"},
                    { Id : 15, Name : "RUNYENJES"},
                    { Id : 16, Name : "CHUKA"},
                    { Id : 17, Name : "MATUU"},
                    { Id : 18, Name : "MTWAPA"},
                    { Id : 19, Name : "KARURUMO"},
                    { Id : 20, Name : "KATHWANA"},
                    { Id : 21, Name : "MERU"},
                    { Id : 22, Name : "KIRITIRI"},
                    { Id : 23, Name : "KIVAA"},
                    { Id : 24, Name : "CHIAKARIGA"},
                    { Id : 25, Name : "ISHIARA"},
                    { Id : 26, Name : "MITUNGUU"},
                    { Id : 27, Name : "TUNYAI"},
                    { Id : 28, Name : "KIBUGU"},
                    { Id : 29, Name : "NKUBU"},
                    { Id : 30, Name : "kitui"},
                    { Id : 31, Name : "SIAKAGO"},
                    { Id : 32, Name : "MOMBASA"},
                    { Id : 33, Name : "VOI"},
                    { Id : 34, Name : "THIKA"},
                    { Id : 35, Name : "EMBU STAGE"},
                    { Id : 36, Name : "NAIROBI ERUSHA HSE"},
                    { Id : 37, Name : "MWINGI"},
                    { Id : 38, Name : "KYENI"},
                    { Id : 39, Name : "KANYONYO"},
                    { Id : 40, Name : "KABATI"},
                    { Id : 41, Name : "KATHAGERI"},
                    { Id : 42, Name : "KATHAGERU"},
                    { Id : 43, Name : "NENO MWEA OFFICE2"},
                    { Id : 44, Name : "kisasi"},
                    { Id : 46, Name : "KAEWA"},
                    { Id : 47, Name : "RUIRU"},
                    { Id : 48, Name : "CHANGAMWE"}
                ],
                valueType: "string",
                valueField: "Id",
                textField: "Name",
            },

            { name: "PARCELS", type: "text", width: 60, validate: "required" },
            { name: "CREATED AT", type: "text", width: 100, validate: "required" },
            { name: "VERIFIED AT", type: "text", width: 100, validate: "required" },
            { name: "VEHICLE", type: "text", width: 70 },
            {
                name: "VERIFIED",
                type: "text",
                width: 50,
                filtering: false,
                validate: "required",
                itemTemplate: function(value) {
                    return value == 1 ? '<i style="color: green;font-size: 16px" class="ti ti-square-rounded-check"></i>' : '<i style="color: red;font-size: 16px" class="ti ti-xbox-x"></i>';
                }
            },
            {
                type: "control",
                filtering: false,
                itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
                    return $("<a>")
                        .attr({
                            href: "#",
                            'data-bs-toggle': 'modal',
                            'data-bs-target': '#modal-outgoing',
                            'data-id': item.DELIVERY
                        })
                        .addClass("ti ti-eye-down")
                        .css({
                            "font-size": "15px",
                            "text-decoration": "none"
                        })
                        .html('<span class="sr-only"></span>');
                }
            }

        ],
    });
});


This part of the select JSGRID DOCUMENTATION can help
